Error with intlTelInput Library When Submitting AJAX Request
I'm encountering a problem with my checkout page where I utilize AJAX request submission. However, after integrating the intlTelInput library, I'm unable to submit the form successfully. There are no visible errors being thrown either. It seems that the form simply refuses to submit after the integration of the library.
Could someone please assist me in troubleshooting this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"
#order_summary.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/css/intlTelInput.css"
    />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <%= form_for @invoice, url: by_now ? get_otp_m_site_store_event_ticket_path(@admin_setting.id, params[:id]) : purchase_m_site_store_event_ticket_path(@admin_setting.id, params[:id]), html: by_now ? {method: :post, remote: true} : {class: "selling_event_form payment-checkout-form", id: "#{@selling_event.by_now ? 'purchase_event_packages' : '' } payment_form"} do |f| %>
    <%= render partial: "donor_form", locals: {bidder: bidder, f: f} %>
    <%= render partial: 'm/shared/payment_page', locals: {f: f} %>
  <% end %>
</body>
  <script>
    const phoneInputFields = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=tel]");

    phoneInputFields.forEach(function(phoneInputField) {
      const phoneInput = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField, {
        utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js",
      });
    });

    const info = document.querySelector(".alert-info");

    function process(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      phoneInputFields.forEach(function(phoneInputField) {
        const phoneNumber = window.intlTelInputGlobals.getInstance(phoneInputField).getNumber();
        const fieldName = phoneInputField.getAttribute('name');
        info.style.display = "";
        info.innerHTML += `Phone number for ${fieldName} in E.164 format: <strong>${phoneNumber}</strong><br>`;
      });
    }
  </script>
</html>


#donor_form.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <title>International telephone input</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Your Information</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label>First Name<span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="[donation][first_name]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" value="<%= bidder.first_name unless bidder.blank? %>" id="donor_first_name"  required='required' lettersonly='true' onchange="same_name_to_all_ticket(true)">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label>Last Name<span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="[donation][last_name]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" value="<%= bidder.last_name unless bidder.blank? %>" id="donor_last_name" required='required' lettersonly='true' onchange="same_name_to_all_ticket(true)">
          </div>
        </div><!--/row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label>Email address<span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Your receipt will be mailed here" class="form-control" id="donor_email_id"
            name="[donation][email]"  value="<%= bidder.email unless bidder.blank? %>" required='required' email='true' onchange="same_name_to_all_ticket(true)">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6" id='removeDiv'>
            <label>Phone<span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
            <input id="phone2" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" value="<%= bidder.phone_number unless bidder.blank? %>"phonenumber='true' onchange="same_name_to_all_ticket(true)">
          </div>
        </div><!--/row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="" name="[donation][contact_status]"> It's Ok to contact me in the future
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <% if current_bidder.blank? %>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <%= check_box_tag "[donation][sign_up_as_member]" %> Sign up as member ?
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--/panel-->
  </body>
</html>


#payment_page.hrml.erb


<% @active_payment_method = @auction_admin.admin_active_payment_method %>
<% @method_type = @active_payment_method.payment_method_type %>
<% @bidder = current_bidder.present? ? current_bidder : @bidder %>
<% @customer_payment_profile = @bidder.get_payment_profile(@auction_admin, @method_type) if @bidder.present? %>
<% kiosk_site = request.url.include?('kiosk') %>

<% if @active_payment_method.present? %>
  <center>
    <% if @customer_payment_profile.present? && !kiosk_site %>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block green btn btn-primary" id="btn-for-new-card-form" onclick="showPaymentForm()">Pay with new card</a>
    <% end %>
  </center>
  <div class="credit-card-form">

    <% if @auction_admin.allow_auth_net_payment? || display_cc_form(@auction_admin) || @auction_admin.allow_stripe_payment? %>
      <div id="paymentable">
        <div id="auth_card_form">
          <% if @auction_admin.allow_auth_net_payment? %>
            <%= render partial: '/shared/auth_card_form' %>
          <% elsif display_cc_form(@auction_admin) || @auction_admin.allow_stripe_payment? %>
            <%#= render partial: '/m/shared/address_section' if @auction_admin.allow_payhub_payment? && params[:controller] != "m/site/donation" %>
            <%= render partial: '/shared/nmi_card_form' %>
          <% end %>

          <% if !kiosk_site && (@auction_admin.allow_auth_net_payment? || @auction_admin.allow_tsys_payment? || @auction_admin.allow_payhub_payment? || @auction_admin.allow_card_connect_payment? || @auction_admin.allow_stripe_payment?) %>
            <% if is_admin_require_cc_to_place_bid(@auction_admin) && @customer_payment_profile.blank? %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag :is_admin_want_to_store_cc, 1 %>
              <%= check_box_tag :is_admin_want_to_store_cc, 1, true, disabled: true %> Your Card info will be registered as the event requires a credit card to be on file.
            <% else %>
              <%= check_box_tag :is_admin_want_to_store_cc %> Do you want to register your CC for fast checkout?
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <%# unless @auction_admin.allow_stripe_payment? %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 payment_button">
              <% button = params[:controller].split('/').last == 'event_tickets' ? 'Buy Now' : 'Submit' %>
              <%= button_tag button, data: { disable_with: 'Processing...' }, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block item_payment_btn green btn btn-primary payment_button_class" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        <%# end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <% unless @auction_admin.payment_method_exists? %>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <b>Please contact Auction Admin to Pay the Invoice</b>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% if @customer_payment_profile.present? && !kiosk_site %>
    <hr>
    <center style="border: 1px solid; padding: 20px;">
      <span style="font-size: 25px;"><b>Card : </b><%= @customer_payment_profile.card %></span>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :return_path, params[:return_path] %>
      <%= button_tag "Pay with saved card", data: { disable_with: 'Processing...' }, onclick: "payWithSavedCard(this)", class: "btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block green btn btn-success" %>
    </center>
  <% end %>

  <script>
    <% if @customer_payment_profile.present? && !kiosk_site %>
      $(".credit-card-form").hide();

      function showPaymentForm() {
        $(".credit-card-form").show();
        $("#btn-for-new-card-form").hide();
        document.getElementById("credit_card_card_number").value = '';
        document.getElementById("credit_card_cvc").value = '';
      }

      function payWithSavedCard(button) {
        $(".credit-card-form").hide();
        $("#btn-for-new-card-form").show();
        document.getElementById("credit_card_card_number").value = '4111111111111111';
        document.getElementById("credit_card_cvc").value = '123';

        var form = button.form;
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'hidden'; input.value = 'Pay with saved card'; input.name = 'commit';
        form.appendChild(input);

        form.validate({
          submitHandler: function(f) {
            if ($(f).valid()) {
              f.submit();
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    <% end %>

    <% unless @auction_admin.allow_stripe_payment? %>
      $("#payment_form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
          if ($(form).valid()) {
            $('.payment_button_class').val('Process..');
            $('.payment_button_class').addClass('disabled').attr("readonly", "true");
            form.submit();
          }else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    <% end %>
  </script>
<% else %>
  <center>
    <h3>Payment Settings are not setup for this event. Please contact to the auction admin.</h3>
  </center>
<% end %>

I have added This changes to my code
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/css/intlTelInput.css"
    />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    const phoneInputFields = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=tel]");

    phoneInputFields.forEach(function(phoneInputField) {
      const phoneInput = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField, {
        utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js",
      });
    });

    const info = document.querySelector(".alert-info");

    function process(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      phoneInputFields.forEach(function(phoneInputField) {
        const phoneNumber = window.intlTelInputGlobals.getInstance(phoneInputField).getNumber();
        const fieldName = phoneInputField.getAttribute('name');
        info.style.display = "";
        info.innerHTML += `Phone number for ${fieldName} in E.164 format: <strong>${phoneNumber}</strong><br>`;
      });
    }
  </script>

            <input id="phone2" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" value="<%= bidder.phone_number unless bidder.blank? %>"phonenumber='true' onchange="same_name_to_all_ticket(true)">

I add type and id (id="phone2" type="tel")

I'm not getting any error, as soon as I remove 'type='tel'' the form gets submitted, but the form doesn't submit on 'type='tel''.
